# Sort products by date Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch, date

```
$this->_collection->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC'); // not working
$this->_collection->setOrder('created_at', 'DESC'); // not working
//$this->_collection->setOrder('position', 'DESC');// this is working
```

I'm using class Toolbar extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar
Any idea how can I do similarly?

Comment: Are You want to sort products by date on list page ?

Comment: you can see "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146727/sort-products-by-date" this.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using should work to sort a collection by the product `created_at` attribute

```
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
```

However I am not sure if extending `Toolbar.php` will let you change the current product listing sort order.

If you want to add `created_at` as a sort option or make it the default sorting option for product listing pages follow the instructions here to enable sorting for this attribute.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/287793/7863

You can then set this as the sorting option per category, or as the default sorting option for all product lists in admin *Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Storefront*.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Are you want to add the new filter option "Date" in product list page
> ?**

step 1 : Create **di.xml** file at below path,

path : **Vendor/module/etc**

add the below code in **di.xml** file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config">
        <plugin name="catalog_config_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Config"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
        <plugin name="catalog_productlist_toolbar_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList\Toolbar"/>
    </type>
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\ListSort">
        <plugin name="Trootech_Image::ListSort" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Config\Source\ListSort" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Step 2: Create new **Toolbar.php** class below path,

path :  **Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList**

add the below code in **Toolbar.php**,

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\ProductList;


class Toolbar
{
    public function afterSetCollection(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar $subject,
        $result
    )
    {
        $currentOrder = $subject->getCurrentOrder();
        $dir = $subject->getCurrentDirection();
        $currentDirection = $subject->getCurrentDirection();
        if ($currentOrder == "date") {
            if ($currentDirection == 'asc') {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('created_at', 'desc');
            }
            else {
                $subject->getCollection()->setOrder('created_at', 'asc');
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Step 3: Create new **ListSort.php** class below path,

path :  **Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Config\Source**

add the below code in **ListSort.php**,

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model\Config\Source;


class ListSort
{
    public function afterToOptionArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config\Source\ListSort $subject, array $result): array
    {
        \array_push($result, ['label' => __('Date'), 'value' => 'date']);
        return $result;
    }

}
```

step 4 : Create new **Config.php** class at below path,

path : **Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model**,

add the below code in **Config.php**,

```
<?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Model;


class Config
{
    public function afterGetAttributeUsedForSortByArray(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig, $options)
    {
        $date = ['date' => __('Date')];
        $options = array_merge($options, $date);
        return $options;
    }
}
```